# How to change image based on condition in Angular JS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to show an image instead of text according to the data coming in the response of an API.

- If true - access symbol,
- If false - deny symbol should be shown.

I tried but I am getting the link in the display not the image.

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>device id</td>
      <td>device unique id</td>
      <td>access status</td>
      <td>current time</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>{{ access.id }}</td>
      <td>{{ access.devid }}</td>
      <!--<td>{{ access.status }}</td>-->
      <td>{{statusValues[access.status]}}</td>
      <td>{{ access.CurrentTime }}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
</div>
  <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('customersCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
      $http.get("http://example.com/get")
        .then(function (response) {
        $scope.access = response.data.sensorsdata;
        $scope.statusValues = {
          'true': 'http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/custom-icon-design/flatastic-9/256/Accept-icon.png',
          'false': 'https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/musthave/256/Cancel.png',
        }
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simpy add the `img` tag with `ng-src` like so:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">
      <table>
          <tr>
              <td>device id</td>
              <td>device unique id</td>
              <td>access status</td>
              <td>current time</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>{{ access.id }}</td>
              <td>{{ access.devid }}</td>
              <td><img ng-src="{{statusValues[access.status]}}"/></td> 
              <td>{{ access.CurrentTime }}</td>
          </tr>
     </table>
</div>

<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('customersCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
        $http.get("http://example.com/get")
            .then(function (response) {
                $scope.access = response.data.sensorsdata; 
                $scope.statusValues = {
                    'true': 'http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/custom-icon-design/flatastic-9/256/Accept-icon.png',
                    'false': 'https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/musthave/256/Cancel.png',
            }
        });    
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following synthax in your [`ngSrc`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc):

```
<img ng-src="{{statusValues[access.status]}}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<td><img ng-src="{{statusValues[access.status]}}"/></td>
```

you are missing an image tag

Comment: @Swapna you are welcome. If this answer was helpful please upvote and accept as answer. thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
<img ng-src="{{statusValues[access.status]}}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this code:

```
  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">
          <table>
              <tr>
                  <td>device id</td>
                  <td>device unique id</td>
                  <td>access status</td>
                  <td>current time</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td>{{ access.id }}</td>
                  <td>{{ access.devid }}</td>
                  <td><img ng-src="{{statusValues[access.status]}}"/></td>
                  <td>{{ access.CurrentTime }}</td>
              </tr>
         </table>
    </div>

    <script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('customersCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
            $http.get("http://example.com/get")
                .then(function (response) {
                    $scope.access = response.data.sensorsdata; 
                    $scope.statusValues = {
                        'true': 'http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/custom-icon-design/flatastic-9/256/Accept-icon.png',
                        'false': 'https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/musthave/256/Cancel.png',
                }
            });    
        });
    </script>
```

You had been missing the closing for `<img>` tag `"/>`

Comment: can u tell me how to refresh this page in javascript function.

Comment: <a href="javascript:location.reload(true)">Refresh Page</a> or location.reload(); helps you to refresh your current page.

Comment: <a href="javascript:location.reload(true)">
                        <table>...</table></a>.can u write like this ?

Comment: do u want to reload your table or full page?

Comment: need to refresh only one table. is it possible to refresh if the data is changed int the database. so that we can avoid page refresh in each second

Comment: can we use like this setInterval( function() {...}

Comment: On what circumstances do you want to reload, on a button click or auto refresh or change of any value?
If you are providing an id to your table and $( "#myTableId" ).load( "#myTableId" ); It may work as per your need.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133897/discussion-between-vishnu-s-babu-and-swapna).